# std::getline( basic_istream<...> &&input, basic_string<...> &str ) with rvalue-"input"

Tags: c++, istream

There's a newer version of std::getline with C++11. It accepts a rvalue "input"-parameter. But why there is a rvalue-parameter, i.e. the fuction would consume the "input"-parameter, leaving the input-parameter empty after the call ?

Comment: In [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1771.html), the mentioned need is to _"allow string I/O to work with rvalue streams"_ (Section 21). This proposal was written _assuming that the rvalue reference proposal documented by N1377, N1690 and N1770 becomes part of the C++ language._ If you go through [N1690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1690.html#Use%20of%20Rvalue%20Streams) you can clearly see the _use of rvalue streams_.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine it's for code where the stream is constructed as part of the call to `getline`, e.g

```
std::string s = ...;
std::string s2;
getline(std::istringstream(s), s2);
```

This code would take the first line from s and put it in s2, for instance.

Code like this would not be legal with the older version of `getline` because the first parameter of that is a non-const reference.